# dynamic associative array in d

Tags: arrays, d, associative, lang

I want an associative array in d programming language.  The key is a struct with two shorts.  Easy so far.

```
struct kie { short a; short b; }
short[kie] possibles;
```

Problem is I want to hold more than value per key.  Dynamic would be useful so it can grow and shrink **per key**
When I try to allocate a dynamic array as value to a to key i.e

short[] temp;
   ...
   possibles[k] = temp;

I get the understandable error
   su.d(30): Error: cannot append type short[] to type short

How do I declare an associative array where the values can be a dynamic array of numbers?

Comment: did you try `(short[])[kie]` you could even alias the `short[]` to something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `Value[Key]` is an associative array that maps values of type `Key` to values of type `Value`. If you want a map of `kie` to `short[]` then you need to declare exactly that:

```
short[][kie]
```

That should do the trick.